# custom web component event call back function in tag

Tags: javascript, native-web-component

```js
class UioKey extends HTMLElement {
 ...
 eKey(){windows.alert('class  eKey function')}
 
 
 }
 
 function eKey(){
 eKey(){windows.alert('document eKey function')}
```

```html
<template id="uio-key-temp">
    <div class="uio-key">
         <div class="i" onclick="eKey()"></div><span></span>
    </div>
</template>
```

when clikcing on the .i div agot the document ekey that is firing, i want 
the class ekey() to be fired
if i omit the dodument eKey() fuction i got function eKey() undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` will only work with globally defined functions.

Here is a *very quick hack* that allows you to use a class function.

```js
// Class for `<uio-key>`
class UioKey extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = '<div><div on-click="eKey">div</div><span>span</span></div>';
    let a = shadow.querySelectorAll('[on-click]');
    a.forEach(
      el => {
        const handlerName = el.getAttribute('on-click');
        el.addEventListener('click', this[handlerName]);
      }
    );
  }

  eKey() {
    window.alert('class  eKey function');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('uio-key', UioKey);
```

```html
<hr/>
<uio-key></uio-key>
<hr/>
```

I use a custom attribute `on-click` as a way to grab all elements that want a click handler then I take the value of that attribute and use it as the class function name and pass it into the `addEventListener` function.

Comment: so and what i have to  put argument like on-click="ekey(x,y,z)" specialy when i want [this0] to be as part of argument ,wher [this0] is the sub elemnt pointer

Answer (score 1):

Alternatly to @Intervalia's answer, you could use the `getRootNode()` method and then the `host` property to access the Custom Element object from inside the Shadow DOM.

```js
class UioKey extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = uio-key-temp.innerHTML
  }
  eKey(){ 
    window.alert('class eKey function' ) 
  }
}
customElements.define( 'uio-key', UioKey )
```

```html
<template id="uioKeyTemp">
    <style> .i { background: gray ; height: 10pt } </style>
    <div class="uio-key">
         <div class="i" onclick="this.getRootNode().host.eKey()"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<uio-key></uio-key>
```

Note that it's always a good practice to use inline scripts because in some situations they can be disabled (for security reasons).